# Cubic Spline class for Obj C or C?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, c, spline, cubic

I need to use natural cubic spline interpolation in an iPhone app.  Does anyone know of a class for Obj C or C that resembles this: 
http://www.ee.ucl.ac.uk/~mflanaga/java/CubicSpline.html

"performing an interpolation within a one dimensional array of data points, y = f(x), using a cubic spline."

Comment: can't opengl es do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this [article](https://github.com/pppoe/Sample-CurveFit#readme) 
This is a sample for Curve Fitting. It uses Cubic Spline Interpolation, and Bezier Spline Curve.

Answer (score 0):

I have implemented it in Javascript. Since there are only several functions (2 "public" functions + internal Gauss-Jordano elimination), conversion to C is pretty straightforward (replace "var" with "int"/"float" etc.).

Article: http://blog.ivank.net/interpolation-with-cubic-splines.html

Code: http://www.ivank.net/blogspot/cspline/CSPL.js

Hope it helps :)

Answer (score -2):

Check out the Docs for UIBezierPath

Comment: Bezier paths and cubic splines are different. Bezier path requires you to provide control points, cubic spline requires only points which are lying on the curve and it interpolates the curve.

Comment: Indeed. However 3rd order (i.e cubic) Bezier curves which have 2 control points can be made into nice smooth first derivative continuous  curves with a fairly straightforward control point rule.